# When I select another option in Angular Mat-Select dropdown it changes the location of the dropdown

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

The dropdown should appear below the select element but if I select the second value the dropdown will appear over the top of the select element which isn't right. I removed any css that would affect this so not sure why its happening. See Screenshots below of the problem:

[Correct location if default value is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHTEt.png)

[Dropdown box appears onto of select element if any other value is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCvou.png)

The code in question:

```
            <mat-form-field class="status-field" appearance="outline">
                <span class="field">Field</span>
                <mat-select formControlName="field" [disabled]="customFieldFilters.length === 0">
                    <mat-option value="internal" (click)="changeFieldFilter(false);">Test 1</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="status" (click)="changeFieldFilter(false);">Test 2</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
```

I removed all css that would impact it and it still occurs. The element is located inside its own component that is located inside an overlay of a parent component so maybe that is impacting it because the default Mat-Select from angular doesn't behave this way.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution by adding the following code to the `mat-select` element:

```html
<mat-select formControlName="field" [disabled]="customFieldFilters.length === 0" disableOptionCentering panelClass="dropdown-style">
```

`disableOptionCentering` and adding a class that has the following:

```css
::ng-deep .dropdown-style {
  margin-top: 20px !important;
}
```

Not a fan of using `::ng-deep` but it did the job and time is limited.